# Google analytics custom event values

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm sending custom event values like this

```
ga('send', 'event', category, action, label, value);
```

All fields are displayed in report except the value property.
Any ideas where I can find this value?
Or maybe there is any other way to send theese values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common problem with values is that Google Analytics doesn't accept decimal values, only integers. But if you're asking where exactly can you see values in the report, then it's Behaviour > Events > Pages, for example:
[image: Behaviour > Events > Pages]

Comment: Plus keep in mind that value is a metric  (i.e. values are added up, not broken down in separate lines like dimensions are).

Answer (score 1):

Event values can be set for more than just Page dimensions. You can see them in Behaviour - Events, as mentioned previously, but you can see them under Top Events too. And in this view you can select nearly any Dimension as Primary Dimension and even break it down further by selecting a Secondary Dimension. The values will appear in the Event Values column. As also mentioned elsewhere, the values must be set as integers, and the displayed values are aggregated typically as an average.